# Why base address of GDT(global descriptor table) differ in intel x64 processor?

Tags: kernel-mode, segmentation, intel

I have created a simple linux kernel module to get the base address of GDT table:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/const.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>

// try changing segment selector to  null 3.4.2
// try swapg in 64 bit 3.4.4


static inline uint64_t get_gdt_base1(void)
{
    struct desc_ptr gdt;
    __asm__ __volatile__("sgdt %[gdt]"
                 : /* output */ [gdt]"=m"(gdt));
    return gdt.address;
}


int __init start_init(void)
{

    uint64_t gdt_base = get_gdt_base1();
    printk(KERN_INFO "Address of gdt is %llx\n", (long long)gdt_base);
}

static void __exit end_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Unloading the driver\n");
    return;
}

module_init(start_init);
module_exit(end_exit);


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL V3");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Shubham Dubey");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("CRO register ");
```

When I have loaded and unloaded the module few times. The output that I am getting are as follows:
1st run: `Address of gdt is ffff88024f249000`
2nd run: `Address of gdt is ffff88024f2c9000`
3rd run: `Address of gdt is ffff88024f249000`
4th run: `Address of gdt is ffff88024f2c9000`
...
...

Technically, the GDT base should be constant. But I am receiving two different address which isn't the normal behavior. 
Can anyone have a good explanation for this?

PS: Running debian in 64 bit intel processor

Answer (score 2):

IIRC on Linux GDT is separate for each processor so you’re probably seeing the addresses for different processors.

Comment: Oh right. Never thought about that. That is probably the correct explanation but do you know or point me to some link for why each processor has different GDT?

Comment: This is borderline off topic anyway, try Stack Overflow or LKML.